# Fuel Resistant Plastics

Tags: fuel-system

The environment inside the fuel tank sounds pretty bad when considering saturated petrol vapour. In tank electric pumps are common these days. What sort of plastic should the wire be made from? What fuel is worse? Petrol? Diesel? Alchohol? Sure, plactic fuel cans exist and even plastic fuel tanks, like on a ford focus, but what about the internal wire?

Comment: Wires under the bonnet also need to be resistant and have temperature added...

Comment: The wiring isn't inside the fuel tank.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Yes, there is. Most modern fuel injected vehicles have the fuel pump inside the tank ... there has to be some way to get power to it. I can guarantee you, there are wires running inside the tank.

Answer (score 1):

Those are mostly [fluoropolymers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoropolymer) (Viton, ETFE to name two).

As with most things that are fluorinated, those cables are unaffected by most chemicals (good), expensive, biopersistant (not good for the environment) and produce hot hydrofluoric acid (especially bad) when burnt.

The search term you need is "cable chemical resistance chart"

A nice one:

https://www.sab-cable.com/cables-wires-harnessing-temperature-measurement/technical-data/cables-and-wires/chemical-resistance.html